# Bootstrap input button not aligning with other fields

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [bryancorrell.com](http://bryancorrell.com/FilterButton.PNG))</sub>

I was able fix the alignment issue, but then I lose the rounded corners on the inputs and can't figure out how to get them back. See the link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/yzw8q28q/5/

```
<form class="simple_form form-inline" novalidate="novalidate" action="/dashboard/school" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
  <div class="form-group select required filter_discipline_id">
    <select class="select required form-control" placeholder="Discipline" name="filter[discipline_id]" id="filter_discipline_id">
      <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1">HW</option>
      <option value="2">SW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary form-control" />
  </div>
</form>

<br /><hr /><br />

<div class="input-group">
  <form class="simple_form form-inline" novalidate="novalidate" action="/dashboard/school" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
    <div class="form-group select required filter_discipline_id">
      <select class="select required form-control" placeholder="Discipline" name="filter[discipline_id]" id="filter_discipline_id">
        <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">HW</option>
        <option value="2">SW</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary form-control" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ruby Code that's generating the HTML form:

```
<%= minimal_form_for :filter, url: @form_path, method: :get, html: {class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.input :discipline_id, 
  collection: Discipline.all, 
  include_blank: '- Discipline -', 
  selected: params[:discipline_id] %>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Filter', class: "btn-primary form-control" %>
</div>
```

It looks like simple_form is injecting the "btn" class. Not sure how to stop that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary form-control" />
</div>
```

replace by

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn-primary form-control" />
</div>
```

there's no need to call the classes multiple times and in this case, the .btn is causing your issue

Tested on your fiddle, works like a charm ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response - The classes were duplicated because I simple_form puts class="btn btn-default" on the button by default. I removed my "btn" injection, but how do I stop simple_form? I added my Ruby/Rails code above - sorry for not including it initially.

Comment: I don't know anything about Ruby/Rails, or simple_form, but, can you pass "f.button" like "f.input" and see what happens?

Comment: Good idea - I fiddled around a bit and looks like f.submit does not inject class="btn":

<%= f.submit 'Filter', class: "btn-primary form-control" %>

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply remove the `btn` class off the input.

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn-primary form-control" />
```

Or you can add the following to your own css:

```
.form-group .btn {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

** Updated **: When filing the bug report I noticed I had the margin bottom backwards.

Comment: Yea, it's kind of annoying because simple_form adds class="btn" and I'm not certain how to stop that.

Comment: I would recommend going with the second option. Create a css file for your app (if you don't have one already) and add the css above. Bootstrap will probably fix it similar to what I did and you won't notice any ill effects in future updates this way. I may even PR the change myself.

Comment: Just spent quite a bit of time troubleshooting this with bootstrap. The css you are using is not pure bootstrap. It appears that multiple css files are being combined and a css reset is being added right after bootstraps code, which is changing the way bootstrap behaves. Without those resets the bootstrap code is working as expected. Bootstrap does not set a margin-bottom of 15px on input or select elements.

Answer (score 0):

On the class btn you have a

`margin-bottom:0px;`

Remove that line and it will align properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response - where do I have "margin-bottom:0px;"?

Comment: It's within your bootstrap css file

Comment: I'm just importing bootstrap, so I can't really change it's implementation:
<at>import "bootstrap-sprockets";
<at>import "bootstrap";

Comment: Would always advise you to upload your own library.

Comment: I actually think there are a lot of benefits to using publicly hosted libraries (e.g. cloudfare and google). With so many websites using bootstrap, it's likely a user will already have the bootstrap css cached and not need to load it. In the case of Rails, it generates a single css file from all the sources, that probably doesn't help there, but I don't see a reason to maintain my own copy of bootstrap. I control the version in my gemfile, so it won't change unless I allow it. I think I agree with Victoria that this looks like a bootstrap bug.